# How to address alternative XPath selector if the original one does not exist?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using scrapy (https://scrapy.org/) to crawl over a lot of websites (nearly 300) and save the title and date in a json. The title is on mostly website the first `H1`. But the date is tricky. Now, I'm using this XPath selector:

```
item['date'] = response.xpath("//time/text()").get()
```

But the website use different kinds of formatting the date. Sometimes as `span`, sometimes as normal paragraphs, sometimes as `time` and other using a `a` tag.

Question: How can I implement something like an `if then else` structure to `item`, to tell the spider look for different elements if the first is not existing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [Item Loaders](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) and pick first non-empty value:

```
l.add_xpath('date', '//first/xpath')
l.add_xpath('date', '//second/xpath')
l.add_xpath('date', '//third/xpath')
```

And in `items.py`:

```
date = scrapy.Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())
```